# F# - Retrofit Record to Html Query List

Tags: types, f#

In F#, is it possible to retrofit a record type to a list extracted from a web query?

```
let customers = 
  organization.CssSelect("div.Customers")
  |> List.map(fun a -> a.InnerText().Trim(), a.AttributeValue("href"))
  // [("1  A  abcdef  Alpha"); ("2  C  aabbcc  Bravo")]

type Customer = {id:string; loc:string; code:string; name:string}
```

so that I can access "customers.id" or "customers.name" for further processing. If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, then there is no built-in magic for this, but I think writing code to do one more `List.map` and create the record is not something that's worth hiding behind magic:

```
type Customer = {id:string; loc:string; code:string; name:string}

let customers = 
  organization.CssSelect("div.Customers")
  |> List.map (fun a -> a.InnerText().Trim(), a.AttributeValue("href"))
  |> List.map (fun (id, name) -> { id = id; name = name; code = ""; loc = "" })
```

If you used some magical trick to fit the data into the record, you'd likely lose a lot of checking (e.g. when using reflection) and you'd lose the explicit way of specifying default values for record fields like `loc` and `code` in this example.

Comment: Tomas, Thanks for the quick reply. As I have no control over the web page in question, I am trying to extract the record data from a web response - [("1  A  abcdef  Alpha"); ("2  C  aabbcc  Bravo")] - so, ideally, I would like to process all fields, if possible. I am willing to accept that I will lose some validation checks in so doing. As an aside, I really enjoyed your book on Functional Programming!

Comment: @matekus Thanks! As for a more unchecked but flexible approach, you could represent the parsed data as a dictionary or a map `Map<string, string>` with the keys based on what's on the web site and value being the parsed value. It's not as nice as a record, but it lets you parse anything that comes from the web.